# Django | Error al insertar nombre de archivo de imagen dentro de ruta de imagen

Tags: django

Necesito meter dentro de una ruta static, un for para mostrar el nombre de archivo de imagen que se guarda en la base de datos. Claro que **a veces imagenNombre es null**, ya que no todos tienen imagen. Pero devuelve error. ¿Qué sucede?

**Devuelve error:**

Invalid block tag

Código:

```
<img width="40%" src="{% static 'files/img/
    {% for pregunta in preguntas %}
      {{ pregunta.imagenNombre }}
    {% endfor %}
' %}">
```

Modelo:

```
class Pregunta(models.Model):
    categoria = models.ManyToManyField(Categoria, null=True, blank=True)
    textoES = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    textoEUS = models.ManyToManyField(Euskara, null=True, blank=True)
    imagenNombre = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

View:

```
def pregunta_list(request, categoria_id):
    preguntas = Pregunta.objects.filter(categoria=categoria_id).order_by('id')
    paginator = Paginator(preguntas,1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    preguntas = paginator.get_page(page)
    totalPaginas = paginator.num_pages
    return render(request, 'pregunta/pregunta.html', {'preguntas': preguntas, 'totalPaginas':totalPaginas, 'page':page})
```

Comment: Estas haciendo tonterías xD, no tiene sentido hacer eso, ademas de que da error, motivo suficiente para no hacerlo... que quieres hacer exactamente?

Comment: Estoy seguro de que habrá manera más sensata, lógica de hacer el código. xD Objetivo:Utilizando paginator, en cada página muestra una pregunta, como para muchas de las preguntas tengo una imagen, en el modelo he metido una columna imagenNombre (con el nombre del archivo de la imagen), para mostrarlo insertándolo en la ruta static. No se si me he explicado bien. Podría guardar la ruta completa static como nombre y mostrarlo en src="", pero no se qué es lo más adecuado.

Comment: Adjunta el código del modelo.

Comment: Julian por que no utilizas un campo `ImageField`?

Comment: ok, si es como se hace, así lo haré. (peco de novato). Te agradezco la información.

Comment: OK y recuerda que seria así con dicho campo: `{{ pregunta.nombre_del_campo_imagefield.url }}`, seria la URL de la imagen.